# Find the Size of Expo React Native OTA Update

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

After a new managed Expo app (eg: v2) is published, and before the existing deployed apps (eg: v1) download the new OTA updates, is there a way to know the size of the downloaded required for this OTA update?

Answer (score 2):

I wish they added support for this in the Expo SDK but here is what I recommend.

Send a **HEAD** web request to the **Bundle URL** (Retrieved from the Manifest object from Updates.checkForUpdateAsync() function) and get the header "**Content-Length**" value. This will be the size of the OTA update.

Detailed documentation of the Manifest object can be found [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/how-expo-works/#expo-manifest). URL you want to send the head request is the value of "**bundleUrl**" key.